# Customer order total by month, w/ all customers listed, even if customer had no orders in a month, in one SQL statement?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Get a list of all customers order totals by month, and if the customer has no order in a given month, include a line for that month with 0 as the order total. In one statement? Totals already computed, no need for aggregate function.

Use of the coalesce function is acceptable.

Given list of customer order totals by month:

```
create table orders (cust char(1), month num, exps num);
insert into orders
    values('a', 1, 5)
    values('b', 2, 4)
    values('c', 1, 8);
```

And a list of customers:

```
create table custs(cust char(1));
insert into custs
    values('a')
    values('b')
    values('c')
    values('d');
```

Generate this table:

```
cust, month, exps
 a, 1, 5
 a, 2, 0
 b, 1, 0
 b, 2, 4
 c, 1, 8
 c, 2, 0
 d, 1, 0
 d, 2, 0
```

Comment: database you are using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can easily be done using `generate_series()` in Postgres. Of with a recursive common table expression in ANSI SQL.

Comment: @vkp That would be SAS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select or1.cust, a.[month], sum(coalesce(or2.[exps], 0)) as exps
from (
    select 1 as[month] union all select 2
) a cross join (select distinct cust from custs) or1
left join orders or2 on or2.[month] = a.[month] and or2.cust = or1.cust
group by or1.cust, a.[month]
order by or1.cust,a.[month]
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67edb/6)

And another version with picking up all existing months from the table. Results are same for our test data:

```
select or1.cust, a.[month], sum(coalesce(or2.[exps], 0)) as exps
from (
    select distinct [month] from orders
) a cross join (select distinct cust from custs) or1
left join orders or2 on or2.[month] = a.[month] and or2.cust = or1.cust
group by or1.cust, a.[month]
order by or1.cust,a.[month]
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67edb/5)

Comment: Fixed. I've changed cross apply to cross join. Could you use it?

Comment: Selecting your answer because CROSS JOIN is more readable I think and also use of sqlfiddle in demonstrating answer.

Answer (score 0):

Making the cartesian product of customers and months was the first crack in the egg... and then a left join/coalesce w/ the result.

```
select all_possible_months.cust,
       all_possible_months.month,
       coalesce(orders.exps,0) as exps
from
       (select order_months.month,
          custs.cust
       from
          (select distinct month
           from
             orders
           ) as order_months,
          custs
        ) all_possible_months
left join
        orders on(
             all_possible_months.cust = orders.cust and
             all_possible_months.month = orders.month
             );
```